# Is there a way to restrict access to a particular node?

Tags: 8, nodes, routes, users

One of my teammates created a simple page that displays links to important contents. However, since it is simple content, the page itself is restricted but the link still shows up in the main menu.

I'm looking for a way to add a permission such as `custom_module.permission.yml` where the client will be able to define who can access this page.

Is there a way to do so without installing any external module?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this module **[Permissions by Term](https://www.drupal.org/project/permissions_by_term)**

> Frontend Features
>
> - Restricts users from accessing the nodes related to specific taxonomy terms by their roles and/or specific user accounts.
> - Restricts users from access to forbidden nodes in views.

Tag the node to the specific taxonomy term and restrict access to nodes tagged with that specific node.